# Wrapping a REST API in Spring database CRUD methods so it can be used as a @Repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

So we currently have a Spring boot production application which communicates with two different data sources.

It has the typical "controllers, managers, and services".

These classes have a host of database .save .find and .delete methods.
This is a production application, and these methods are present in way too many places.

```
someRepository.save(someObject);
someOtherRepository.findAll(someCriterion);
```

I want to find a way to either

a) Make these methods communicate thru an api where API Returns the result

b) Make changes to Respository classes that these methods are called on so that a REST API serves these as opposed to the database.

This is supposed to be done as a business requirement.

Comment: This seems to be a badly formulated question, where you are just asking how to do something without showing anything you have tried so far.

Also, you are confusing terms here, API is something the Spring application (Spring is not a database, it is a framework or applicaiton using that framework) would expose in order to allow interaction with the given CRUD operations. 

So in essense, please formulate a specific question, showing what is it you have tried and that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conceptually this is simple/possible - create a class that implements [JpaRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html) or [CrudRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html) but calls REST API methods rather than JDBC methods.

However, practically this will be very laborious to implement, in particular support for `@Transactional`. Full implementation would require the REST API to support concepts like commit and rollback.